# Will a RODE-K2 Mic work with a Focusrite 2i2 Interface and a basic Laptop for high quality male vocals?

Tags: theory, voice, recording, microphones, setup

I want to buy a K2 for my bedroom setup to record male vocals.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  It doesn't take much computer power by today's standards to record a few tracks of audio.  And the Focusrite is a competent interface.   You could probably get just as good a result with a mic half the price though.   Above a certain price level mics might sound different, but not really 'better'.

Have you got a really nice-sounding room to record in?  That makes a lot of difference.

Comment: I have normal room and have not done anything to make it more suitable for recording, in the future I do plan to as now I am only starting to get serious. I was looking to get a Rode NT1 but then came across the K2 and now wanted to get this but since I am new I am quite confused, I read online that I need a 'pre amp gate' or I would get a lot of noise I am not sure what this means. Also apparently a tube Mic needs the tube replaced often?

Comment: There is no automatic need for a noise gate.  Or for frequent tube replacement.   But I think the NT1 would be a better choice for you at present.

Comment: Thank you, I have a medium voice but do go slightly low sometimes but not with much bass would you recommend the NT1 or NT1a?

Comment: To be honest, if you want to warm up your voice. I'd suggest working close to a SM58 first.  I expect you can borrow one to try, there's lots around! (But beware of fakes.)